# My reset password password system gives me a a data base error

Tags: php, mysqli

I have been trying to make a reset password system where my code is as follows:

```
<?php  ob_start();
include "includes/header.php";
include "includes/db.php";
//session_start();
include "includes/navigation.php";

if(isset($_GET['reset']) && isset($_GET['token'])) {

$token = $_GET['token'];
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($connection, "SELECT username, user_email, token FROM users WHERE token=?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $token);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $username, $user_email, $token);
mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);
if(!empty($username)) {
if(isset($_POST['password']) && isset($_POST['confirmPassword']) && $_POST['password'] == $_POST['confirmPassword']) {
$password = $_POST['password'];
$hashedPassword = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array('cost'=>12));
echo $hashedPassword;
echo $user_email;

$stmt = mysqli_prepare($connection, "UPDATE users SET token= '', user_password= '{$hashedPassword}' WHERE user_email= ?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $user_email);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);


}

} else {
  header("Location: index.php");
}
} else {
  header("Location: index.php");
}




?>
```

Now the case is that the first query is working well. The token is inserted successfully in the database to the account requesting to the reset password and it successfully got the data from the database.

The issue comes when the new password and its confirmation are inserted by the user. Although the password is hashed successfully, there is a problem inserting it into the database.

It got me the "mysqli_stmt_bind_param() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given". For sure the problem is not in the connection as the connection already worked in the above query. I have been going around checking what is wrong with the statementquery but I cannot recognize any mistake.

Appreciate your help.
Thanks

Comment: Close your statement.  You try to load 2 queries on an active connection. Either free the results or close the statement, or make a second instance of your connection variable.

Comment: post your error

Comment: Daniyal, his error is right in the middle of the post ;) `mysqli_stmt_bind_param() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given`

Comment: why  `'{$hashedPassword}'`? Tried without the curly brackets?

Comment: `mysqli_prepare` either returns an object if it is was successful or `false` if an error occurred. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php#refsect1-mysqli.prepare-returnvalues. Check the comment by @Dorvalla for a hint.

Comment: @Dorvalla Yeah this was the problem. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have amended your code and documented as best where possible where you have went wrong, and why my corrections should work.

```
<?php  ob_start();
include "includes/header.php";
include "includes/db.php";
//session_start();
include "includes/navigation.php";

if(isset($_GET['reset']) && isset($_GET['token'])) {

$token = $_GET['token'];
//I have amended your query, you do not need to grab the token if the condition is that it is the same as something you already have, as $_GET['token'] AND $token will always be the same.
$query = "SELECT username, user_email FROM users WHERE token = ?");
$stmt = $connection->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $_GET['token']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($username, $user_email);
$stmt->fetch();
$stmt->close(); // You did not close your query connection. 
// To use a new query you must first close the previous one.

if(!empty($username)) {
if(isset($_POST['password']) && isset($_POST['confirmPassword']) && $_POST['password'] == $_POST['confirmPassword']) {
$password = $_POST['password'];
$hashedPassword = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array('cost'=>12));
echo $hashedPassword;
echo $user_email;

// Previously you tried to insert a PHP variable into a query, which is not possible
// in (and defeats the point of) prepared statements. Rather than put in $variable
// replace them with '?' . (not including quotation marks)
$query = "UPDATE users SET token = null, user_password = ? WHERE user_email = ?";
$stmt = $connection->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $hashed_password, $user_email);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();    

}

} else {
  header("Location: index.php");
}
} else {
  header("Location: index.php");
}
```

Additionally, your output buffering at the beginning of the document can most likely be avoided if you place your db.php before your header, and also the code I've provided before your header. (This is just based on some errors I've seen in other's code.)

The error you described in your original post "mysqli_stmt_bind_param() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt" means that most likely there is an error in the query syntax, which is the main element I have amended.

Comment: Thank you so much cmprogram. I got your point and I will check it when I go home.

Comment: It worked. Just by closing the query everything was ok. Thank you so much.